# How to use date in the index in the same way as in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to follow the excellent answer from [How to make day of the week flags from datetime index in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62478968/how-to-make-day-of-the-week-flags-from-datetime-index-in-pandas). The code I am using is:

```
pd.concat((testdf, pd.get_dummies(testdf.index.weekday)), axis=1)
```

testdf looks like:

```
            United Kingdom
Time (CET)                
2020-02-15         1739771
2020-02-16         1649750
2020-02-17         1887394
2020-02-18         1922006
2020-02-19         1957194
2020-02-20         1878259
2020-02-21         1890076
2020-02-22         1677928
2020-02-23         1688218
2020-02-24         1948947
```

And pd.get_dummies(testdf.index.weekday) looks like:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
6  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
7  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
8  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
9  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

And yet the result looks like:

```
    United Kingdom  0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000004   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000005   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000006   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000007   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000008   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000009   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-02-15 00:00:00.000000000   1739771.0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-02-16 00:00:00.000000000   1649750.0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-02-17 00:00:00.000000000   1887394.0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-02-18 00:00:00.000000000   1922006.0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-02-19 00:00:00.000000000   1957194.0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-02-20 00:00:00.000000000   1878259.0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-02-21 00:00:00.000000000   1890076.0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-02-22 00:00:00.000000000   1677928.0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-02-23 00:00:00.000000000   1688218.0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2020-02-24 00:00:00.000000000   1948947.0   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I think this is because when I make the index using `set_index` the type got changed. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.concat((testdf.reset_index(), pd.get_dummies(testdf.index.astype('datetime64[ns]').day_name())), axis=1).set_index('Time (CET)')
df = df[['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']]
df
```

Comment: What is reset_index() doing here exactly?

Comment: in the example you indicated found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62478968/how-to-make-day-of-the-week-flags-from-datetime-index-in-pandas — 'date' is not an index but an ordinary column. In your data set df.reset_index() converts an index into an ordinary column.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to get `day_name()` to work as well? testdf.index.day_name() is not valid.

Comment: Like getting Mon, Tue, Wed, etc.?

Comment: Yes. The answer in the linked answer has `pd.concat((df, pd.get_dummies(df['date'].dt.day_name())), axis=1)`  This gives the right names to the columns.

Comment: Your answer also gives me an extra column. I can use set_index to move it back to the index however.

Comment: pd.concat((testdf.reset_index(), pd.get_dummies(testdf.index.weekday)), axis=1).set_index('Time (CET)')

Comment: Thanks I got that to work but I am not sure how to get the days of the week using day_name any more.

Comment: Try the answer above.

Comment: AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt' . That's the same problem I found. index.dt is not alowed.

Comment: Try the answer above.

Comment: AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: Try the answer above.

Comment: The days are now in the wrong order. E.g. "Friday  Monday  Saturday  Sunday  Thursday  Tuesday  Wednesday"

Comment: Try the answer above.

Comment: Do you understand why the days are in the wrong order?

Comment: Probably it has something to do with what comes first in the index itself. By the way, did the code solve the problem?